# Mysql to Elasticsearch - won't create index and export data

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, elasticsearch, logstash

I am attempting to import a MySQL table into Elasticsearch.It is a table containing 10 different columns with a an 8 digits VARCHAR set as a Primary Key. MySQL database is located on a remote host.

To transfer data from MySQL into Elasticsearch I've decided to use Logstash and jdbc MySQL driver.

I am assuming that Logstash will create the index for me if it isn't there.

Here's my logstash.conf script:

```
input{ 

jdbc {      
jdbc_driver_library => "/home/user/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar"

jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://[remotehostipnumber]/databasename"

jdbc_validate_connection => true

jdbc_user => "username"

jdbc_password => "password"

schedule => "* * * * *"

statement => "select * from table" 

} 

}

output  

{
  elasticsearch 
{

index => "tables"
document_type => "table"
document_id => "%{table_id}"
hosts => "localhost:9200"
}stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

When running logstash config test it outputs 'Configration OK' message:

```
sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --configtest -f /home/user/logstash/logstash.conf
```

Also when executing the logstash.conf script, Elasticsearch outputs:

```
Settings: Default filter workers: 1
Logstash startup completed
```

But when I go to check whether the index has been created and data has also been added:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tables/table/_search?pretty=true'
```

I get:

```
{
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [ {
  "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
  "reason" : "no such index",
  "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
  "resource.id" : "tables",
  "index" : "table"
} ],
"type" : "index_not_found_exception",
"reason" : "no such index",
"resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
"resource.id" : "tables",
"index" : "tables"
 },
 "status" : 404
}
```

What could be the potential reasons behind the data not being indexed?

PS. I am keeping the Elasticsearch server running in the separate terminal window, to ensure Logstash can connect and interact with it.

Comment: Can you run logstash with `--debug` so you can see more output? Can you ping your database host `remotehostipnumber`?

Comment: Since your are using the stdout output, you should be able to check if Logstash receive the data and to know if the problem is with logstash retrieving the logs or sending them to Elasticsearch

Comment: looking at the --debug output it looks like it connects, I can also ping the database host. Really stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who end up here looking for the answer to the similar problem.

My database had 4m rows and it must have been too much for logstash/elasticsearch/jdbc driver to handle in one command.

After I divided the initial transfer into 4 separate chunks of work, the script run and added the desired table into the elasticsearch NoSQL db.

Answer (score 0):

use following code to export data from mysql table and create index in elastic search

```
echo '{
"type":"jdbc",
"jdbc":{

"url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_database_name",
"user":"your_database_username",
"password":"your_database_password",
"useSSL":"false",
"sql":"SELECT * FROM table1",
"index":"Index_name",
"type":"Index_type",
"poll" : "6s",
"autocommit":"true",
"metrics": {
            "enabled" : true
        },
        "elasticsearch" : {
             "cluster" : "clustername",
             "host" : "localhost",
             "port" : 9300 
        } 
}
}' | java -cp "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0/lib/*" -"Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:////etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0/bin/log4j2.xml" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
```